# Micropython Xbee - How do I get the Xbee serial number and convert it to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xbee, micropython

I am using an Xbee3 pro with micropython. I'm trying to convert the device serial number to a string. Here is the code.

```
import xbee
from time import sleep


serial = xbee.atcmd("SL")
serial = serial.decode("utf-8") 
while True:
    print("Sending broadcast data >> %s" % serial)

    try:
        xbee.transmit(xbee.ADDR_BROADCAST, serial)
        print("Data sent successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Transmit failure: %s" % str(e))
    sleep(2)
```

The data transmits successfully, but I only get three ugly characters that are unreadable.

The result of:

```
serial = xbee.atcmd("SL")
print(serial)
```

is

```
'A\x92\xa4\xbf'
```

I really just need to convert 'A\x92\xa4\xbf' to 4192A4BF.

Comment: After staring at the characters for some time I realized that \x is a delimiter. If you just remove the \x you end up with A92a4bf which is the serial number if you were to substitute A for 41. Is there a protocol where capital A = 41?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the fact that 41 is the hex representation of "A". [see this link](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: the actual result might be `'\x41\x92\xa4\xbf' ` and the program just translates the first hex code to `'A'` since `'\x'` is the hex indicator. or something like this...

Comment: If you open the XTCU problem that Digi distributes for configuring the Xbee the low serial number is: 4192A4BF

Comment: yes i understand. what i thought as a possible reason for your case, is that the program translates just the first hex code and leaves the others as they are.

Comment: Do you have the ubinascii module (i.e. does `import ubinascii` succeed)?

Comment: @GeorgeBou I'm not sure you understand Python strings properly - the `\x` is part of how Python *represents* a non-printable value in a string when printing it, there are no literal `\ ` or `x` characters in the string. OP's mistake is to try decoding it into a string in the first place - see [tomlogic's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58173829/24447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work:

`''.join('{:02x}'.format(x).upper() for x in xbee.atcmd("SL"))`

You're taking each byte of the bytearray (`for x in ...`) and formatting it as two uppercase hexadecimal characters (`'{:02x}'.format().upper()`), then joining those together with nothing in between (`''.join()`).

Comment: Yes, that looks good and doesn't depend on any other libraries. It might be worth mentioning explicitly that the asker should NOT be trying to `decode` the response from UTF-8 as per their original code - it's not a UTF-8 encoded string, it's just a sequence of four byte values.

Comment: Absolutely.  I should have commented on that, but chose to take the return value of `xbee.atcmd()` directly.  My guess is that certain `ATSL` values would trigger an exception since they aren't valid UTF-8 sequences.  (And thanks for fixing the code in my answer.)